# Display textbox multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML part contains a textarea with a label.The user has to enter text and the form should be submitted and refreshed for the user to enter text again for say 5 more times. How can I do this using Javascript?
This is the html code:

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label for="ques"><p id="p1">Question:</p></label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="ques"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="sub" onclick="func()">Next</button>
```

The javascript code:

```
var x=1;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="Question"+x;

function func()
{
var frm = document.getElementsByName('myform')[0];
frm.submit();
frm.reset();  
return false;
}
```

Comment: You want to display 5 `textarea` or what ?

Comment: Where are you sending the text from the textarea element to? Is the page these snippets reside in possibly a PHP page?

Comment: Or wouldn't you rather want to send the 5 texts to a back end PHP (or other server script) page using AJAX?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Yes but not one below the other. Once the user enters text and clicks next, another textbox should be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two methods you can use. Both of these require you to add a submit button to your form, like this:

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label for="ques"><p id="p1">Question:</p></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="ques"></textarea>
  </div>
  <!-- add this button -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
</form>
<!-- no need for a <button> out here! -->
```

#### Method 1: sessionStorage

`sessionStorage` allows you to store data that is persistent across page reloads.
For me info, see the MDN docs on [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). This method requires **no** external libraries.
Note that in this method, your page **is** reloaded on submit.

```
window.onload = function() {

  var myForm = document.forms.myform;

  myForm.onsubmit = function(e) {

    // get the submit count from sessionStorage OR default to 0
    var submitCount = sessionStorage.getItem('count') || 0;

    if (submitCount == 5) {
      // reset count to 0 for future submissions
    } else {
      // increment the count
      sessionStorage.setItem('count', submitCount + 1);
    }

    return true; // let the submission continue as normal
  }

  // this code runs each time the pages loads

  var submitCount = sessionStorage.getItem('count') || 0;

  console.log('You have submited the form ' + submitCount + ' times');

  if (submitCount == 4) {
    console.log("This will be the final submit! This is the part where you change the submit button text to say \"Done\", etc.");
  } 

};
```

#### Method 2: AJAX with jQuery

If you don't mind using jQuery, you can easily make AJAX calls to submit your form multiple times without reloading.
Note that in this example your page is **not** reloaded after submit.

```
window.onload = function() {

  var myForm = document.forms.myform;
  var submitCount = 0;

  myForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
    $.post('/some/url', $(myForm).serialize()).done(function(data) {
      submitCount++;
    });

    console.log('You have submited the form ' + submitCount + ' times');

    if (submitCount == 4) {
      console.log("This will be the final submit! This is the part where you change the submit button text to say \"Done\", etc.");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  };
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You shuld create an array and push the value of the textbox to the array in func().

Answer (score 0):

We can create a template using a `<script type="text/template>`, then append it to the form each time the button is clicked.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('sub');

const appendNewTextArea = function() {
  const formEl = document.getElementById('form');
  const textareaTemplate = document.getElementById('textarea-template').innerHTML;
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = textareaTemplate;
  formEl.appendChild(wrapper);
}


// Call the function to create the first textarea
appendNewTextArea();

btn.addEventListener('click', appendNewTextArea);
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" id="form">

</form>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="sub">Next</button>

<script id="textarea-template" type="text/template">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label for="ques"><p id="p1">Question:</p></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="ques"></textarea>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: This helps but is there a way for me to keep track of the number of times the textbox appears? There shouldn't be a next button after the 5th time

Comment: Where should I call the appendTextArea() function? In the JS file?

Comment: little typo `<script type="text/template>` --> `<script type="text/template">`